# I cannot find pydev django project in eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, project, pydev

Hi
after I have installed python django and so on, I add the python to eclipse and it is fine, and when I went to new->project...>pydev-> "here I am not able to see the pydev django project", while I just can see the pydev project and pydev google project....
Can anyone please solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press `CTRL + N` (or go to menu `File > New > Other`)
2. Open Pydev sub tree (or type `django`) and double click on `Pydev Django Project`
3. Click on `Next` and follow the wizard

Here is the [Pydev official explanation](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html#creating-a-new-project) with screenshots. As you'll see you can also convert an existing project to a Django project.

Answer (score 1):

I met the problem before. I think the reason is that I install Pydev before Django. You can try to reinstall Pydev.